# KairosDB TAG NAMES

Tags: kairosdb

Is there a way to get the tags from a specific metric name ? When I make the  GET request I get all the possible TAG NAMES that exist in the database. But at the localhost when I try to group the metric by tags I see that the tags, which are assosiated with the metric, are listed on a dropdown menu.

The  [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/wiki/ListTagName) has only 1 request for tag names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ideed, you have the QueryMetricTags REST API endpoint.
http://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/restapi/QueryMetricTags.html

BTW, the documentation you are referring to on google code is outdated (But I'm also sure you will find the emthod there as well, this is not new feature), you should look at the one on github.

Comment: I checked this is also in the older documentation: https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/wiki/QueryMetricTags :)